# Errors in deleteing user's profile in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Controller(Users) and Action:-**

```
def destroy

@user=User.find(params[:id]).destroy

flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."

redirect_to(root_path)

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/destroy', to: 'users#destroy'
*#(resources:users)* have already mentioned
```

views:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

NOW,
Everything is going fine till  the message box **"confirm: 'Are you sure?'"** and then when I clicking **"OK"**
gives me two notices one highlighted with yellow **"You are not authorized to access this page".**

and other with green **"You have to confirm your account before continuing"**.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Are you using specific gems handling Authentication/Authorizations ?

Answer (score 0):

Your link_to will not generate a link to the '/destroy' you mentioned in the routes.rb, but to /user/1. But that should not interfere when you used the 'resources', where also a delete action is defined.

Second: check your Ruby/Rails version. The link_to has undergone some changes to v3 that could cause this behaviour.

Check where those yellow and green messages are displayed. Probably in VIEWING the user instead of deleting it.